# Spring batch metadata tables already exist exception

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application writing to a MySql database. On first run, everything runs as expected and the write is a success. However, after restarting the service on subsequent runs the following exception arises: `Table 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' already exists`. This exception arises for each of the metadata tables that Spring tries to create, and the write to my actual 'business logic' database does not occur.

The full log:

```
INFO org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql]
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql]: CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE ( JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , VERSION BIGINT , JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' already exists
```

Is there any Spring Batch configuration/annotation I can set to tell Spring to write to the existing database instead of just quitting and raising an exception if the database already exists?

The `org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql` file looks like the following:

```
-- Autogenerated: do not edit this file

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT ,
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

so there is no error handling in the case that the table exists already.

Comment: Set the spring.batch.initialize-schema=never and set the ddl-auto to false.

Comment: Common properties, you can find the batch config here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi ddl-auto must be one of the following values: none, validate, update, create, and create-drop.

Comment: Please set the ddl-auto to none.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi I made these updates, but the result did not change.

Comment: Last change set generate-ddl=false and try again :-)

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Added the line. Still did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168852/discussion-between-vikram-palakurthi-and-queue).

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Thank you, but I am presently unable to use the chat service.